# Spring - Failed to read HTTP message. Required request body is missing

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to edit an exam object but I am getting this error:
Failed to read HTTP message. Required request body is missing.

I believe the error is that You can't send a request body with an HTTP GET request but I don't know how to do it instead.

The user selects an exam to edit and I want the HTML to pass that examId to the controller.

My Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/editExam.html{examId}", method = { 
RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.PUT })
public String editExam(@ModelAttribute("exam") @PathVariable(value = 
"examId")Long examId, @RequestBody Exam exam,Model model, BindingResult 
result) {

         examRepository.findOne(examId);
            model.addAttribute("examTitle", exam.getExamTitle());
            model.addAttribute("examGradeWorth", exam.getExamGradeWorth());
            model.addAttribute("examGradeAchieved", exam.getExamGradeAchieved());


             exam.setExamTitle(exam.getExamTitle());
         exam.setExamGradeWorth(exam.getExamGradeWorth());
         exam.setExamGradeAchieved(exam.getExamGradeAchieved());

          examRepository.save(exam);

    return "editExam";
}
```

editExam.html:

```
  <form action="#" th:action="@{/editExam.html{examId}}"  th:object="${exam}" method="put">


    <table>
        <tr>
        <td> Exam Title:</td>
         <td><input type="text" th:field="*{examTitle}" th:text="${exam.examTitle}"/></td>
    <!--    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('examTitlee')}" th:errors="*{examTitle}">error message</td>  --> 
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td> Exam grade worth </td>
            <td><input th:field="*{examGradeWorth}" /></td>
        <!--    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('examGradeWorth')}" th:errors="*{examGradeWorth}">error message</td> -->
            </tr>  
            <tr>
                <td>examGradeAchieved</td>
                <td><input th:field="*{examGradeAchieved}"/></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit">Submit post</button></td>
                </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: In your HTML you did not specify the type of  `method` on submit action.

Comment: `<form th:method="put">`

Comment: @MehrajMalik I actually did but for some reason it didn't show, edited it there. I think the error might be that You can't send a request body with an HTTP GET request however I don't know how it should be done instead.

Comment: you should use POST instead of GET if you want to send requestbody

Comment: @cool I tried that and it fixed the error however now when I click to edit the exam it doesn't bring me to the right HTML page anymore it just has it one the default localhost main page. Where as before It was bringing me to the right html page.

Comment: @cool It is definitely a mapping issue but I am so bad at that for some reason!

Comment: @cool I even added in this: { RequestMethod.GET , RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT} but the mapping still isn't working its directly the page back to the main page no the edit exam page.

Answer (score 1):

As per best-practices of designing/creating REST APIs, it is advisable that...

- when you are adding any new resource in DB, use `POST` HTTP method
- When you are updating an existing resource, use `PUT` HTTP method
- When you are retrieving resources, use `GET` HTTP method
- When you are deleting any resource, use `DELETE` HTTP method

So in your case, you should use `PUT` HTTP method instead of `GET` while you are updating a resource (exam in your case), and anyway, `GET` HTTP method does not allow user to add a request-body in HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by changing the start of the controller to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editExam.html/id={examId}", method = { RequestMethod.GET , RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
```